# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with multiple IF statements

Tags: mysql, pdo

So, I have a table named invoices which aims to update its column status according to the ammount value when data is re-submitted.

For instance, I have this set of results:

```
<table>
    <thead>
       <tr>
       <th>Sap Code</th>
       <th>Document No.</th>
       <th>Description</th>
       <th>Net Change</th>
       <th>Status</th>
       </tr>        
 </thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>8000000</td>
    <td>123456</td>
    <td>March invoice A</td>
    <td>Not Paid</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

use multiple IF statemets to achieve this, I tried with just one condition but is not working. Not sure if this is a SQL problem or a PDO issue since I'm binding params.

I would like my query to update the status to "Payed" if the ammount is the same and "partyally paid" if the new ammount is less than the current. Status "Not payed" if the record is new.

This is my current query:

```
INSERT INTO invoice (sap_code, document_number, description, net_change, status) 
VALUES (:sap_code,:document_number,:description,:net_change, 'Not payed') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    sap_code= :sap_code, document_number= :document_number, description= :description, 
    status = if(VALUES(net_change) = :net_change, VALUES(status), 'Paid')
```

Any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

NEW TEST (NOT WORKING)

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    sap_code= :sap_code, document_number= :document_number, description= :description, 
    status = CASE WHEN  :net_change = net_change
             THEN 'Paid'
           ELSE 'Partially Paid' END,
    net_change = :net_change
```

Comment: `VALUES(net_change)` is the same as `:net_change`, so the `IF` will always be true.

Comment: Yes, from the manual: "In other words, VALUES(col_name) in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause refers to the value of col_name that would be inserted, had no duplicate-key conflict occurred."

Answer (score 0):

You should be comparing `VALUES(net_change)` with the column in the table, not the parameter being assigned.

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    sap_code= :sap_code, document_number= :document_number, description= :description, 
    status = IF(:net_change = net_change, 'Paid', VALUES(status)),
    net_change = :net_change
```

Comment: This is not working. Besides, I'm not binding :status

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you're trying to do. Why would you use the same code to add a new invoice and pay off part or all of an existing invoice?

Comment: Because in my application the user submits the information via microsoft excel documents.

Comment: Maybe it should be `net_change = net_change - :net_change`, so it reduces the amount by the payment.

Comment: Can you show an example of table contents, the values being inserted, and the desired result?

Comment: @Nelson Put it in the question, you can't put formatting in comments.

Comment: Please, check it now

Comment: It's not helpful. I need to see the original table contents, the rows you're inserting, and what you want the final result to be. I need to see all the cases: inserting a new row, changing the status to Paid, and changing the status to Not Paid.

Comment: I don't know what an HTML table has to do with this. We're dealing with MySQL, not HTML.